# truncating all strings in a dataframe column after a specific character using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a dataframe `df` that contains a list of strings like so:

```
+-------------+
   Products
+-------------+
|     Z9L57.W3|
|     H9L23.05|
|     PRL57.AF|
+-------------+
```

I would like to truncate the list after the '.' character such that 
it looks like:

```
+--------------+
 Products_trunc
+--------------+
|     Z9L57    |
|     H9L23    |
|     PRL57    |
+--------------+
```

I tried using the split function, but it only works for a single string and not lists.
I also tried

`df['Products_trunc'] = df['Products'].str.split('.').str[0]`

but I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Does anyone have any insights into this?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like if you are used to pandas. The truncating in pyspark is a bit different. Have a look below:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
l = [
(  'Z9L57.W3'  , ),
(  'H9L23.05'  ,),
(  'PRL57.AF'  ,)
]

columns = ['Products']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)
```

The [withColumn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) function allows you to modify existing columns or creating new one. The function takes 2 parameters: `column name` and `columne expression`. You will modify a  columne when the column name already exists.

```py
df = df.withColumn('Products', F.split(df.Products, '\.').getItem(0))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+
|Products|
+--------+
|   Z9L57|
|   H9L23|
|   PRL57|
+--------+
```

You will create a new column when you choose a not existing column name.

```py
df = df.withColumn('Products_trunc', F.split(df.Products, '\.').getItem(0))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------------+ 
|Products|Products_trunc| 
+--------+--------------+ 
|Z9L57.W3|         Z9L57| 
|H9L23.05|         H9L23| 
|PRL57.AF|         PRL57| 
+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you cronoik! It works! 
What is the deal with the ```\``` in ```\.```?  Is ```.``` a modifier and used for something else?

Comment: Split takes a regular expression. `.` is a special character and needs to be escaped when you want to match the dot.

Comment: Thank You for that explanation cronoik :)